# If i want to let $\mathbf H \vec f $ become zero,Is there some condition that $\mathbf H$ must be satisfied?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If i want to let $\mathbf H \vec f $ become zero,and $\mathbf H$ is a N by M matrix,$\vec f$ is a M by $1$ column vector,and both $\mathbf H$ and $\vec f $  cannot be a zero matrix or zero column .

Is there some condition that $\mathbf H$ must be satisfied ? for example,N > M? or M < N or M=N?

Comment: Can you take $\vec{f}=0$? Because if you don't suppose that $\vec{f} \neq 0$, then you need no hypothesis on $H$.

Comment: @Milloupe thanks for reminding,i have edited it

Comment: Let $A$ be an arbitrary  N-by-N matrix, then $H=A\Big(I-\frac{ff^T}{f^Tf}\Big)\;$ satisfies $Hf=0$ for any given $f$. This construction does not depend on the relative magnitudes of $M$ and $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of vectors $\vec{f}$ that verify $H\vec{f} =0$ is called the kernel of $H$. Therefore your question is about the conditions on $H$ in order to have a non-zero kernel.

To give you a small example, whichever the dimensions of the matrix are, if it is filled with 0's then all vectors are in the kernel. Thus, the dimensions are not a necessary condition.

What you are interested in, is the rank of the matrix $H$. It is defined as the dimension of the image of $H$, or "column space", i.e. the set of all linear combinations of the column-vectors of your matrix.

This rank has the property $rank(H) \leq min(M,N)$, and also that $rank(H) + dim(kernel(H)) = N$.

So the necessary condition for having a non-zero kernel is to have a rank lower than N. This is immediately achieved if $M<N$ (sufficient condition).

However, if $M \geq N$, then you need to have a rank that is smaller than its maximum theoretical value considering the matrix dimensions. Matrices that have this property are called "singular" or "degenerate", and are non-invertible.

Comment: So you mean that in order to let $H$ multiply a nonzero vector and become zero,that is kernel(H) cannot be a zero vector,we must let  rank(H) < N,that is ,M<N

Comment: so kernel(H) is a vector,if kernel(H) is a zero vector,then dim(kernel(H)) must be zero?